# the lines' points x1, x2, y1, y2 do not coincide with nodes in a radial tree

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js

I try to connect nodes with svg lines in a radial graph but the points x1, x2, y1, y2 do not coincide with nodes. I changed the polar coordinates into Cartesian coordinates but I think I missed something.

here is my [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ericBr1985/UAwx4/).I tried so far to solve the problem

Please help! thanks

```
line.append("line")
      .attr("class", "line")
      .attr("x1", function(d) {return d.source.y * Math.cos(d.source.x-90);})
      .attr("y1", function(d) {return d.source.y * Math.sin(d.source.x-90);})
      .attr("x2", function(d) {return d.target.y * Math.cos(d.target.x-90);})
      .attr("y2", function(d) {return d.target.y * Math.sin(d.target.x-90);})  
      .attr("stroke-width", 3)
      .attr("stroke", "steelblue");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are so close!  Javascript trigonometric functions work in radians, not degrees, so if you account for that, your graph will work.

```
line.append("line")
  .attr("class", "line")
  .attr("x1", function(d) {return d.source.y * Math.cos(Math.PI/180 * (d.source.x-90));})
  .attr("y1", function(d) {return d.source.y * Math.sin(Math.PI/180 * (d.source.x-90));})
  .attr("x2", function(d) {return d.target.y * Math.cos(Math.PI/180 * (d.target.x-90));})
  .attr("y2", function(d) {return d.target.y * Math.sin(Math.PI/180 * (d.target.x-90));})  
  .attr("stroke-width", 3)
  .attr("stroke", "steelblue");
```